# Feedback on PCB antenna design

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, esp32

PCB antenna: 1 & 2 are solder pads for selecting PCB or external antenna. 3 is the UFL connector. What do you think about my design?

[image]

This antenna is for Wifi & Bluetooth on a custom board, using ESP32. For the Pi network I choose: C1: 1.2pF, C2: 1.5pF, L: 1.8nH.

I need some feedback, as this is the first time I have designed an antenna for ESP32.

Trace width from ESP32 to antenna: 0.33mm, copper clearance: 0.66mm. 4-layer PCB.

Comment: What does you analysis show?

Comment: Where did you get the antenna design from?  Was that from an ESP32 design guide?

Comment: It would be much better (and less potential "not-working-moment" later on) to use the pre-fabricated ESP32 module (from Espressif or AI-Thinker) than using the bare ESP32 chip with your own antenna design. Especially if you are new to Electronics or Radio Communication.